# convert the string to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string like this:
`2,100|7,104|15,1110`

How can I convert it so that I get an array like this with the first value before each `|` is the key?

```
Array
(
    [2] => 100
    [7] => 104
    [15] => 1100
)
```

Comment: explode your string two times. First time with '|' and second time with ','.

Comment: Alternative approach using `preg_split`: `$arr = array_filter(preg_split('/\|?\d+,/', $str));` - [demo](https://eval.in/100523)

Comment: @AmalMurali keys of the array are not matching .

Comment: @NambiNarayanan: Ah, missed that requirement. Thanks for pointing that out! It *is* possible to do this with regex, but this is a job for string manipulation functions and regex isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it

```
$str = '2,100|7,104|15,1110';

$arr1 = explode("|",$str);

if(sizeof($arr1) > 0 ){
    $final_array = array() ;
    foreach($arr1 as $data){
            $arr2 = explode(",",$data);
            $final_array[$arr2[0]] = $arr2[1];
    }
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_walk](https://www.php.net/array_walk) and [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) to do this.

```
$array = array();
$string = "2,100|7,104|15,1110";

array_walk(explode("|", $string), function($value) use(&$array) {
    $group = explode(",", $value);
    $array[$group[0]] = $group[1];
});
```

PHP 5.4+

Answer (score 0):

use [explode](https://www.php.net/explode)

```
<?php

$pipeString = "2,100|7,104|15,1110";
$exploded = explode("|", $pipeString);
$outputArray = array();

for($i = 0, $l = count($exploded); $i < $l; $i++){
  $keyValues = explode(",", $exploded[$i]);

  $outputArray[$keyValues[0]] = $keyValues[1];
}

var_dump($outputArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the question, so I'll make one assumption. You could do it this way.

```
    $str = "2,100|7,104|15,1100";
    foreach (explode("|", $str) as $part) {
        $parts = explode(",", $part); 
        $my_array[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Yatin Trivedi said, exploding twice should give you the result that you are after:

```
$string  = '2,100|7,104|15,1110';
$result = array();
foreach (explode('|', $string) as $entry) {
  $values = explode(',', $entry);
  $result[$values[0]] = $values[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function explodeThem($string) {
    $explode0= explode("|", $string);

    for ($i=0; $i<count($explode0); $i++) {
        $explode1 = explode(",", $explode0[$i]);
        $newArray[$explode1[0]] = $explode1[1];
    }

    return $newArray;
}

$string = "2,100|7,104|15,1110";
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(explodeThem($string));
echo "</ pre>";
```